# PHP MYSQL date email reminder

Tags: php, mysql, email

I created a database with 3 fields(**contract_expired, main_applicant_dob and joint_applicant_dob**). How do I send an email to myself to remind myself about these dates? For the **contract_exprired** if matches to the current **dd-mm-yyyy**, auto send an email to myemail@gmail.com. And for the **main_applicant_do**b and **joint_applicant_dob** can I set it to remind me one week in advance when it matches dd-mm?

Answer (score 1):

Write a PHP script that will read the DB fields and check if the conditions are right to trigger the email. Run the PHP script from the command line `php <scriptname>` to see if it works well and then set it up as a cron job.

Comment: how do I set it up as a cron job?